# One line if in Symfony2

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$value = A
$value = ($value == "A") ? 1 : ($value == "B") ? 2 : ($value == "C") ? 3 : null;
```

On this way it's always returns 3. Where do I make a mistake?

Comment: what is the benefit of having this in this way? I normally don't like this, it is horrible to read.... I would go for a switch case...

Comment: Nested ternaries are hard to read and non-intuitive (as you're discovering), and not recommended practise for precisely that reason..... I sincerely hope that whoever needs to maintain your code isn't a homicidal axe-murderer who knows your home address; or even simply that you can remember what it is supposed to be doing in 6-weeks time

Comment: You're assigning A without quotes to $value. If A is a variable that hasn't been declared/populated of course it's null. Put quotes around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need to add brackets for the second and the third condition like this :

```
$value = A
$value = ($value == "A") ? 1 : (($value == "B") ? 2 : (($value == "C") ? 3 : null));
```